# Erro Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Estou preparando o seguinte método de upload de informações:

```
public function uploadProjeto(int $idCategoria, string $titulo, string $area, string $ano, string $endereco, string $descricao){

       
        

        $insertProject = $this->mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO tbprojetos (id_categoria, titulo, area, ano, endereco, descricao) VALUES ('?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?')");
        $insertProject->bind_param('isssss', $idCategoria, $titulo, $area, $ano, $endereco, $descricao);
        $insertProject->execute();
    
    
    }
```

Comment: A sua pergunta poderia ter mais informação.  O que e `$this->mysql`.

Comment: a string sql não deveria ter aquelas aspas simples dentro do values, tente assim `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`. Além disso, são 6 parametros, tem um "?" a mais

Comment: Ah sim, o $this->mysql é para fazer a conexão com o Db dado o parâmetro do construtor da classe, que seria 

`
class Projeto {
    private $mysql;

    public function __construct(mysqli $mysql){
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }
 `